# How do I import an image in to react Im using rails 7

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, react-rails

> ERROR] Could not resolve "logo.png" │ import logo from 'logo.png'
> 08:55:46 js.1   |         ╵

```
import logo from './logo.png'

import logo from './images/logo.png'

import logo from '../images/logo.png'

import logo from './images/logo'
```

I keep getting: could not resolve as an issue for the import

Expecting the image to render in react

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json`:

in the `scripts` section, add `--loader:.png=file` to the following line:

```
"build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
```

ex:

```
"build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --loader:.png=file",
```

This will allow you to load `png` files.

Then in `jsx` you can just import and use your image like normal:

ex.

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from '../path/to/your/image.png'

export default () => (
  <img src={Image} />
)
```

See [here](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#file) for more information.

Answer (score -3):

I setup rails react on rails instead and with web packer its very simple to import images

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).